# Php is messing up my javascript, button won't open

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript button on my site that is supposed to popup a URL at random from an external txt file of urls (one per line) but the php keeps messing up the javascript by inserting an extra break.

```
 <a href="#" onClick="javascript:window.open('http://something.com/a.php?u=<?php echo $url ?>', 'yea', 'height=520, width=400, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar = yes, toolbar=no');"><img src="clic.jpg" border="0"></a>

<?php 

$urls = @file('urls.txt');
$num = count($urls)-1;
$url = $urls[rand(0,$num)];

?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `;` on your first `<?php echo ... ?>`

Comment: if that echo is the only statement inside the php code block the `;` can be omitted

Comment: I doubt it since one's server-side and one's client-side.

Comment: This code is exactly as you posted? because you are `echo`ing `$url` before you assign a value to it.

Comment: Also if you pass the url as a GET parameter remember to encode it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use *file()* like this:
`@file( 'urls.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );`

Answer (score 0):

[file()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads the entire file in to an array WITH the newlines still attached.

Try this:

```
$url = trim($urls[rand(0,$num)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = trim($urls[rand(0,$num)]);
```

Each line has the CR (and LF) characters that mark a new line at its end. The `trim` function will remove such extra whitespace characters from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$urls = @file('urls.txt');
$num = count($urls)-1;
$url = $urls[rand(0,$num)];
$url = trim($url);
?>
```